# Passing variables to a subprocess in python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

I don't know if this is the correct form

```
num=8
num2=10
num=subprocess.check_output("num/2", shell=True)
num2=subprocess.check_output("num2+7", shell=True)
```

Comment: Bash doesnt have access to your python variables, try something like that `subprocess.check_output("{}/2".format(num), shell=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'num/2'` is just the string "num/2". If you want it to be the variable `num`, you need to interpolate it, e.g., with an f-string `f'{num}/2'`.

Also if you're trying to use bash for division, you'll have to add double parentheses for arithmetic expansion:

```py
>>> num = 8
>>> subprocess.check_output(f'echo $(( {num}/2 ))', shell=True)
b'4\n'
```

Python first interpolates `{num}` into `8`, and then sends `echo $(( 8/2 ))` to shell.